# WCF logging not working, trying to get ANY information on why services don't work

Tags: wcf, trace

I have deployed a few WCF services to a server via a web setup project
they are being hosted in an IIS Application, which appears to be running fine.

However when i try to navigate to the wsdl, nothing is found.

I am trying to set up diagnostics logging, to get some information.

I have followed the advice from here: [wcf trying to set up tracing to debug, not writing to log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850653/wcf-trying-to-set-up-tracing-to-debug-not-writing-to-log-file)

Also, I have tried what is in the referenced [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/diagnostics/tracing/recommended-settings-for-tracing-and-message-logging): under "Recommended Settings for Deployment or Debugging"  .. my web.config has that identical configuration.  But no log file is being created.

Nothing useful in the event viewer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Could be a permissions issue; IIRC those don't always turn up in the event log. Ensure the user IIS runs under has write permissions to the log file path.

Comment: thanks for the idea.  I've temporarily given 'Everyone' full control over c:\logs, but nothing has been written yet.

Comment: Hmm... do the IIS logs indicate the request is being handled? What is the HTTP response code?

Comment: interestingly enough, nothing is showing up in the IIS logs when i try to access it.

Comment: Confirming that this could be due to permissions issue. Opened the log folder, added permissions (troubleshoot w/ Everyone). Worked like a charm! thanks!

Comment: Also confirming that this can be permissions issue (I gave the identity that the service was running under write permission and tracing immediately began to work).  In hindsight, I realize the fact that the service was otherwise running without a hitch indicates a permissions problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is typically the diagnostic config I use. Seems to work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
  ... 
  <system.diagnostics> 
    <trace autoflush="true" /> 
    <sources> 
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" 
              switchValue="Verbose"> 
        <listeners> 
          <add name="sdt" 
              type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" 
              initializeData="D:\wcfLog.svcLog"  /> 
        </listeners> 
      </source> 
    </sources> 
  </system.diagnostics> 
</configuration>
```

If you are not getting any output it may be because your service is not starting correctly. The ServiceHost must be up for diagnostics to output anything. With IIS even though your site is running it does not mean that the ServiceHost started correctly. It's usually a config issue. I'm not a web guy but doesn't IIS write to EventViewer if there is an unhandled exception in the website?

Also, you could try creating a custom ServiceHostFactory. That way your code controls the ServiceHost creation and you can trap any exceptions and log them on your own.

Creating a custom ServiceHost in IIS -> [LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but for the benefit of anyone who might stumble upon the issue:

1. Make sure you have configured both the **system.diagnostics** and the **System.serviceModel/diagnostics** sections configured.
2. Make sure you have them configured in the correct App.config/Web.config file. The thing to note is that **multiple** config files may exist in a project, and the one used depends on the **Build Configuration**.

Personally I had the very same symptom until I noticed that I put the sections
    under **app.config** (in my case, client side tracing), instead of
    **app.DebugLocal.config**. The later was used as my build configuration was set to **DebugLocal**.